# Bot Framework System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException occuring semi-randomly within dialog

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I'm having an issue where my application goes into break mode. This occurs from within a specific dialog called `TourInitiationDialog.cs` but doesn't occur in any other dialogs. I call this dialog from within `OnTurnAsync` in my root dialog the regular way:

```
await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(TourInitiationDialog.id, cancellationToken);
```

Once in this dialog, Visual Studio breaks with this message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7moI.png
When I press `Continue execution` in the picture, I get this:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`
`External component has thrown an exception.`

`'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.9\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'.` `Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[26216] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

I've added a quick gist from the dialog. It breaks at any step after the first step. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/MilesWilde/314efa92b06b38d5da89a90750dfa761

The random nature of this is making it very hard for me to debug. I've looked into the error itself but with no luck so far. Does anyone have any suggestions of why this error might be being caused? It happens on multiple machines too so I don't think it's due to my Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Your image of the Visual Studio message is behind a private Slack instance. Please find a way to expose it publicly. Including the actual raw exception details (i.e. ToString() it) here in the post in a code block rather than via an image would be even better.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the private image, I'll post a new one now. The exception is something that isn't being logged in the traditional way. I'll edit my post and try to explain.